# Weird result from R regarding structural break test

Tags: r, structural-change

I'm trying to detect structural breaks in time series of NAV using 'strucchange' in R.

I have created the NAV by using a simple annualized return of 5% and 10% (no random term). However, after using 'breakpoints' test in R the result is that the break point is not on the point I have changed return from 5% to 10%.

[image: why is the break point not on time ~500]

My code is like:

```
library(readr)
test <- read_csv("D:/Temp/Test/nav.csv")
View(test)
library(strucchange)
testnav = ts(test$NAV)
bp.test = breakpoints(testnav ~ 1)
plot(testnav)
lines(bp.test, breaks = 1)
```

The data I use is [Here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/00lz3qeoo76t5vd/nav.csv?dl=0)

Did I do something wrong? Why isn't it break on time ~500 where the return changed from 5% to 10%?

Comment: Your questioon is a little vague.

Comment: Interesting question.  The "choice" of a breakpoint does seem odd.  Are you interested primarily in understanding the behaviour of R's breakpoints() function?  If so, try this question on a forum dealing squarely with R, maybe StackOverflow.

Comment: still have no idea why it is not break on time ~500 where the return changed from 5% to 10%

Answer (score 2):

The weird breakpoint is found because you just look for changes in a piecewise-constant mean (i.e., a step function). However, you clearly need a piecewise-linear function with changes in the trend slope (and intercept). So instead of `~ 1` you can regress on `~ time(testnav)` for example:

```
bptrend <- breakpoints(testnav ~ time(testnav))
```

The resulting visualization for the 1-break solution is:

```
plot(testnav)
lines(bptrend, breaks = 1)
lines(fitted(bptrend, breaks = 1), col = 4)
legend("topleft", c("observed", "fitted"),
  col = c(1, 4), lwd = 1, bty = "n")
```

[image]